# dijit.byId(divId).attr("href", href) is not working in IE9

Tags: dojo

Am facing the  IE9 compability  issuse . 'onClick' am calling the showLightbox.

```js
function showLightbox(divId,href,title) {
    dijit.byId(divId).attr("href", href);
    dijit.byId(divId).attr("title", title);
    dijit.byId(divId).show();
}
```

This function is working fine in IE8. But when its IE9 it dosen't work. While debugging
   it shows:

> **SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'attr': object is null or undefined**

Can anybody throws views on this, so that it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Version of dojo do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot change the attribtue because the object you're calling it on (in this case `dijit.byId(divId)`) does not exist. Verify the following:

- Is your DOM loaded yet?
- Are your widgets parsed?
- Is the ID correctly?

To give a more detailed response you should provide more information (HTML + the onClick event handler that calls this function). A working example that changes the lightbox properties immediately can be found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/f2Skr/) (using Dojo 1.9).